# Java if statements logistics

Tags: java

If I put getsomething below if statement, would it work? If not, how to make it return
getSomething for each if something.equals(x) statement?
PS:Ignore syntax. If statement is in main method.

```
 if (something.equals(x))){
   return getSomething;

   private void getSomething() {
     String variable1 = "SELECT x from y";
     return;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Are you trying to define a method inside another method?

Comment: When faced with a doubt that goes like "would it work", you can try it yourself. It's not like writing into Eclipse and debugging it would cost you an arm.

Comment: And this is a misuse of the word 'logistics'. Logistics has nothing to do with logic.

Answer (score 2):

This will not work, because Java doesn't allow you to nest method definitions.  Also, you must include empty parentheses `()` on a method call even if there are no parameters, and you can't return the result of a `void` method call.

Answer (score 2):

This would work if you define `getSomething()` as a normal method in that class (and it returned the same type as that method, which at the moment it doesn't as it's void) but you can't nest the method definitions.

If you only want the `getSomething()` method to be used in that one case, just declare it private so it can't be used outside of this particular class.

Comment: What do you mean? You mean inside the main method?

Comment: No, inside the class as another top level method. You can't declare one method inside another this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can't nest methods in that way. Instead, break out your method like this:

```
public String someMethod() {
    if (something.equals(x))) {
         return getSomething();

    return getSomethingElse();
}

private String getSomethingElse() {
    return "SELECT x from y";
}
```